# How to generate easy anagrams preserving punctuation?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing the hint system for a quiz. The hints are to be anagrams of the answers. To make the anagrams easier, I keep the first and last letters the same.

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var easy = function(s) {
    if (s.length <= 1) {
        return s;
    }
    return s[0] + _.shuffle(s.slice(1, -1)).join("") + s.slice(-1);
};
```

For multiple word answers, I want to anagram each word separately. I wrote:

```
var peasy = function(s) {
    return s.split(/\W/).map(easy).join(" ");
}
```

However this loses any punctuation in the answer (replacing it with a space). I'd like to keep the punctuation in its original position. How can I do that?

Here are three examples to test on:

```
console.log(peasy("mashed potatoes"));
console.log(peasy("computer-aided design"));
console.log(peasy("sophie's choice"));
```

My function `peasy` above fails the second and third examples because it loses hyphen and apostrophe.

Comment: Your `easy` function can return `s` if `(s.length <= 3)`. By preserving first and last chars, only strings with length greater than 3 really get shuffled...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting by word separator does the trick:

```
var peasy = function(s) {
    return s.split(/\b/).map(easy).join("");
}
```

Explanation:
`"computer-aided design".split(/\b/)` results in `["computer", "-", "aided", " ", "design"]`. Then you shuffle each element with `easy` and join them, getting something like `"ctemopur-adeid diegsn"` back...

Answer (score 2):

It's more simple to use `String.prototype.replace` instead of splitting:

- you don't need to slice after the first and before the last letter.
- the replacement occurs only on word characters (other characters stay untouched)
- words with less than 4 characters are skipped.
- it's shorter and doesn't need the `easy` function.

```js
var _ = require('underscore');

var peasy = function(s) {
    return s.replace(/\B\w{2,}\B/g, function (m) {
        return _.shuffle(m).join('');
    });
}
```